# Enforce transactions in firebase

Tags: transactions, firebase

I'm currently building my first app with firebase. So far so good, the database is flexible and easy to use, I love it.

I'm building a full web app, meaning that all the code and logic will be executed in the browser. For some updates, I'll need transactions to make sure that the data remains consistent.

But not everybody likes order and consistent data, and I'm worried that some people may try to create their own faulty client to attack my application.

tl;dr: **Is there a way to enforce transactions for certain updates, when we're only using web clients?**

Comment: It shouldn't matter how someone sets data, only what data gets set. In other words, a malicious attack would be against your data integrity, not a deviant method of setting correct and valid data. So you should focus on applying security rules to enforce integrity, not implementation details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't enforce transactions per-se, but you can enforce what their effects on the data will be. For example, if you want a particular field to be only incremented by `1` at a time, you can write security rules like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "counter": {
      ".write": "newData.val() == data.val() + 1"
    }
  }
}
```

In your client code, you can use the `transaction()` function to propertly increment counters, but if someone tries to write data outside of what your security rules enforce that would fail.

Comment: Reminds me of that good ol' thick database development that I loved so much! I will probably need some time to make the mindset switch again, but I'll like it! Thanks for this good reply!